# Connection error when trying to download file from Hadoop Namenode using Python and Docker Compose

Tags: python, hadoop, docker-compose, hdfs

I have my API running on a docker container. Since it uses several services, I wrapped them all in a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.12"

services:
    api:
        container_name: api
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redis
        depends_on:
            - worker
            - redis
    worker:
        container_name: celery
        environment:
            - BROKER_URI=redis://redis
            - BACKEND_URI=redis://redis
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_worker
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: "redis:alpine3.17"
        ports:
            - 6379

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: rete1
```

As you can see, at the end I create a network. I do that because my API works with data stored in Hadoop, whose services run through an other docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    hostname: localhost
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:


networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: rete1
```

For testing purposes I manually uploaded a file on `hadoop_namenode` and I am trying to reach it from the API. The file can be found under the path `/user/dataset/prova.csv` and the owner is `root`.

The command `docker network inspect rete1`  gives me the IP addresses of the containers within the network. The `namenode` container is running at the IP address  `172.21.0.5/16` and it is listening on the port `9870`. The API is running at `172.21.0.9:5000`.

Therefore, I hardcoded `namenode`'s address and the port in the following `test.py` file, that also contains the function I want to launch:

```
import hdfs

HDFS_HOST = "http://172.21.0.5:9870"
client = hdfs.InsecureClient(HDFS_HOST, timeout=60)

def foo(content_url):
    client.download(hdfs_path=content_url, local_path=".")
```

Lastly, this is my `api.py` file, containing the method that calls the function

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restx import Api
from test import foo
import reqparse

api = Api(title="API", version="0.1")
application = Flask(__name__)
api.init_app(application)


parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('content_url', type=str, required=True)


@api.route("/my_endpoint/preprocess", methods=['POST'])
class Preprocess(Resource):
    @api.expect(parser)
    def post(self):
        params = preprocess_parser.parse_args()
        foo(params['content_url'])
```

In order to test my API, I run this code:

```
import requests
requests.post("http://172.21.0.9:5000/my_endpoint/preprocess",
                  json={"content_url": '/user/dataset/prova.csv'
```

But I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9864): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/root/unprocessed.csv?op=OPEN&user.name=root&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&offset=0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5f4c7f01c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

And I don't understand why it says `host='localhost', port=9864` since I specified a different port and a different host. Moreover, if I set as `content_url` a path to a file that does not exist, the API will return an error saying that the file doesn't exist. This means that it successfully connects to the hadoop container, but for some reason fails when it has to download the file. I tried downloading the file using python console, outside the API's container, and everything goes smoothly, but I need this to run within docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The command docker network inspect rete1 gives me the IP addresses of the containers within the network

Those are IPs within the **Docker network** bridge. Plus, I'd recommend using Pyspark or Pyflink to read/write csv data rather than WebHDFS

Within the Docker network you'd use `namenode:9870`, for example, not its ip address. But you need to use actually set `rete1` network on all containers. Or put all your services in one file to share a default network

But I suspect your issue is from `hostname: localhost` on the datanode...

For the POST request to Flask, you can use localhost, if you add ports definition to your api container

Comment: Yes, the problem was indeed in the `hostname: localhost` in the definition of the datanode container. Removing that line solved my issue. I don't have enough reputation to give you an upvote, thank you anyway