# Unable to download data from hadoop's namenode in docker container

Tags: docker, hdfs

I ran the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

Then, on the hdfs server, I created a directory named `user` and I uploaded a file named `foo.csv`. I want to download it from Python. From docker, I can see that the namenode's IP is `172.18.0.2`, and it's listening on port `9870`.
The Python code that should download the file is:

```
import hdfs
HDFS_HOST = "http://172.18.0.2:9870"
client = hdfs.InsecureClient(HDFS_HOST, timeout=60)
client.download(hdfs_path="/user/foo.txt", local_path=".")
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.4', port=9870): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/unprocessed.csv?user.name=FBenedetti&op=GETFILESTATUS (Caused by NewConnectionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA5256B408>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato"))
```

I looked up at previous questions and none of them was helpful. I had a similar problem before, described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76288652/connection-error-when-trying-to-download-file-from-hadoop-namenode-using-python) question, but it was a different situation, and here I am not doing the error that I was making in that situation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the Python code running in a container?  If it is, you can use the Compose service names like `namenode` and `datanode` as host names; if it isn't, the Docker-internal IP addresses are almost always unreachable, and you need to use the published `ports:`.